# .htaccess and WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having problems with my WordPress
My WordPress is installed on a subdomain which assumes `blog.lupinedream.com`.  My provider forwards requests made there to a directory in `/public_html/blog/`.  My landing page is located at `www.lupinedream.com`, that points at two different subdomains for you to choose from:  `forums`, and `blog`.  With that information, here's the question.

What is the proper `.htaccess` configuration to auto-forward all requests (including as well, `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, ... etc. directed at `http://www.lupinedream.com/blog` to `blog.lupinedream.com`?

Reason I'm asking is because WordPress asks for `Site URL` and `WordPress URL`  in **Settings -> General** to allow WordPress to be installed in a subdirectory, but I've been getting weird behavior when I use my current config (broken images, GET and POST not working) when WordPress attempts to internally point requests at `http://www.lupinedream.com/blog/`.  In the address bar, I'm noticing my URL going foobar as well.

---

Config:

**`/public_html/.htaccess`**:

```
Options ExecCGI Includes IncludesNOEXEC SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes

## File Type Specifications
AddType text/html .html .htm .xml
AddType text/plain .txt .text .doc .md .nfo .info
<IfModule mod_cgi.c>
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py .jsp .asp .shtml .sh 
    AddType cgi-script .cgi .pl .py .jsp .asp .shtml .sh
</IfModule>
<iFModule mod_php.c>
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .php53 .phtml .tpl .html
    AddType application/x-httpd-php70 .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .php53 .phtml .tpl .html
</IfModule>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php under_construction.html

## Query limits
<Limit GET POST>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from All
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from localhost
</Limit>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**`/public_html/blog/.htaccess`** :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

WordPress **Settings > General** :

`Site URL` : **http://www.lupinedream.com/**

`WordPress URL` : **http://blog.lupinedream.com/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the structure below `blog.example.com` and `www.example.com/blog` is the same, a redirect would look like

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Since your provider already rewrites `blog.example.com` to `/blog/...`, you should be able to remove the existing `RewriteRules` in `/public_html/.htaccess`.

Comment: I used the subdomain example here:  [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess), but the redirect doesn't seem to work.  If I go to `blog.example.com` I can view page source.  Everything with blog.example.com has two "//" before it in href when accessed from `http://www.example.com/blog`.  This seems to affect external links too somehow, like google.

Comment: Yes, but your Wordpress site lives below `/blog`, doesn't it? And you already have this snippet in `/blog/.htaccess` too.

Comment: Have you put the rewrite rule into `/public_html/.htaccess`?

Comment: No, I put it in `/public_html/blog/.htaccess`.  My bad.  But I found out my CNAME record isn't working correctly from my registrar portal, so I'm doing a registrar transfer too to make sure it works 100%.  I need to transfer it from DynDNS.